# Where should the bitbucket-pipelines.yml pushed to with a development and master branch?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a development and a master branch. I pushed the bitbucket-pipeline.yml to the master branch and realized, that want to run my pipeline on the develop branch. Is it best practice to to commit it first on the development branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in a branch - then the file will be used for pipelines when you commit something to this branch, if you create a PR then the file from the first branch will be used (the same as commit).

The best practice is to have the file in every branch with a config that shares logic for all branches / tags / pull requests and if you need different rules for different branches - simply specify them in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`.

this file I have in every branch:

```yaml
image: satantime/puppeteer-node:12.16.1-buster

pipelines:
    default:
        - step: &Preparation
        - step: &Manual
        - step: &BuildAOT
        - step: &Lint
        - step: &CodeStyle
        - step: &LintTs
        - step: &LintCss
        - step: &UT
        - step: &E2E
        - step: &BuildDocker
    pull-requests:
        '**':
            - step: *Preparation
            - step: *Manual
            - parallel:
                  - step: *CodeStyle
                  - step: *Lint
            - step: *BuildAOT
            - parallel:
                  - step: *UT
                  - step: *E2E
            - step: *BuildDocker
    branches:
        '**': # <- rules for all branches
            - step: *Preparation
            - step: *BuildDocker
        'master': # <- rules for the master branch
            - step: *Preparation
            - step: *UT
            - step: *E2E
            - step: *BuildDocker
```